# Hibernate creates one table as read-only

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I use Hibernate in a project and let it create my tables for all entities. My issue is:

- I have a many-to-many relationship between entity A and entity B
- The link table A_B is created but it is created as read-only

For entity A:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "A")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class A{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "A_B",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_id")
    )
    private List<B> Bs= new ArrayList<>();
}
```

For entity B:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "B")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class B {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "Bs")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<A> As= new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I have another many-to-many relationship and the link table is created fine.
What could cause this?

I tried to drop the schema and regerate it, but it did not fix anything. I also checked my rights, but everything seems fine there.

Comment: have you tried to add `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` param  in class `A` on`@ManyToMany` relation ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa we tried it and it did not change anything. After we changed from List to Set , the problem was solved.